# What do the Get and Set commands in Visual Basic do?

Tags: vb.net

What do the Get and Set commands in Visual Basic do?  I encountered the Get and Set commands in my book's chapter on Object-Oriented Programming.  Here is some code:

```
Public Property SocSecNum() As String
   Get
      Return m_ssn
   End Get
   Set(value As String)
      m_ssn = value
   End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Take a read of: [How to: Create a Property (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-create-a-property)

Comment: If you're a beginner on VB.NET I'd suggest that you look at C# instead as Microsoft is now no longer actively working on VB.NET. It appears that C# will evolve but VB.NET will be locked in time now.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a field, i.e. a member variable, you can get its value:

```vb
var = someObject.SomeField
```

or you can set its value:

```vb
someObject.SomeField = someValue
```

The whole point of a property is that, from the outside, it behaves just like a field but, from the inside, it behaves like methods. That means that you can get and set a property just like you can a field but, on the inside, rather than just straight assignment and retrieval, it actually executes the `Get` and `Set` part of the property definition.

When your project is compiled, they are actually implemented as methods and the property value is stored elsewhere. That might be a dedicated field or it might not. An example of the latter is the `Lines` property of a `TextBox`. The is no dedicated field for that data. What actually happens is that the `Get` part takes the current text, splits it on line breaks and returns the resulting array. Similarly, the `Set` part combines the array provided into a single `String` and sets the `Text`. Two of the most common reasons for extra code are validation and raising events.

A simple field declaration looks like this:

```vb
Public SomeField As SomeType
```

A fully-implemented property looks like this:

```vb
Private someField As SomeType

Public Property SomeProperty As SomeType
    Get
        Return someField
    End Get
    Set(value As SomeType)
        someField = value
    End Set
End Property
```

As you can see, the field is private and, when the property is invoked in code, the getter and setter will get or set the value of that field. Once compiled, that code actually looks like this:

```vb
Private someField As SomeType

Public Function get_SomeProperty As SomeType
    Return someField
End Function

Public Sub set_SomeProperty(value As SomeType)
    someField = value
End Sub
```

As you can see, the getter and setter are literally methods and the property is just syntactic sugar. Java doesn't have properties and Java developers literally write these two methods as accessors for a field.

More recently, the authors of VB have realised that it's laborious to write all that code out over and over for lots of properties so we now have auto-properties. You can simply write this:

```vb
Public Property SomeProperty As SomeType
```

and everything else is implied. There's still a backing field and there is still a getter and a setter but your code is not cluttered up by showing them. This is how you will write most properties these days. As I said before, you'll still need to write the property out in full if you want to add any extra functionality to the getter or setter. Raising a changed event is probably the most common example of that, e.g.

```vb
Public Event SomePropertyChanged As EventHandler

Private someField As SomeType

Public Property SomeProperty As SomeType
    Get
        Return someField
    End Get
    Set
        If someField <> value Then
            someField = value

            OnSomePropertyChanged(EventArgs.Empty)
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Protected Overridable Sub OnSomePropertyChanged(e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent SomePropertyChanged(Me, e)
End Sub
```

In this case, when the property is set, the backing field is set if and only if the new value is different to the old value and then an event is raised to notify listeners of that change in property value. The fact that properties can include extra code like this is why they should be used over fields for public data.

Answer (score 0):

On the Tools menu select Options. Click on Debugging. Uncheck Step over properties and operators

[image]

Create your class thusly. It can be nested in the form class for this little test.

```
Public Class SomeClass
    Private m_ssn As String
    Public Property SocSecNum() As String
        Get
            Return m_ssn
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_ssn = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Now, in the Button.Click create an instance of your class. Set the SocSecNum. Then Get the value and assign it to a text box.

Next set a break point in your code on the first line of the button code. Do this by positioning your cursor on the gray line to the left of the code and clicking.
[image]
Run your program and click the button. You will encounter the break point. You can now step through your code line by line. Use the Step into symbol.

[image]

You will see that when you set the property the Property Procedures Set is called. The value is stored in the `Private m_ssn` variable. Likewise, when you get the property the value of the private variable is returned. Hold your cursor over the m_ssn variable when you are in the Property Procedure and you will see the value stored there.

All this boilerplate code disappears in current versions of Visual Studio where the default Getter, Setter and private member are created for you behind the scenes with auto properties. You can still write the Get and Set and private variable when you need to do things to the input or output.

Comment: Can I suggest that you have an opening paragraph that just states what the `Get` and `Set` do? Then if you wish to go into the debugging stuff that's all good. As it stands now I'm just confused if this long answer actually does answer the question.

Comment: @Enigmativity I would definitely follow your suggestion but jmcilhinney already did an excellent job of explaining in his answer. I was attempting to show what it does. The next to last paragraph is the one with explanation of what it does. I do not go into the OOP theory of why it does this, just what it does. I can still remember how excited I was the first time I saw the debugger jumping into called methods. Often the debugger is never taught to students.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little that can give you an idea
I used this if to easily disable some buttons while process is running
and then when you call the "decrypting = false" the disabled buttons will become enabled

```
Dim dec As Boolean

Private Property decrypting As Boolean
    Get
        Return dec
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        dec = value
        partialFile = False
        btnAddFiles.Enabled = Not dec
        btnAddFolder.Enabled = Not dec
        btnAddKeyFile.Enabled = Not dec
        btnSaveAs.Enabled = Not dec
        txtOutputFileName.Enabled = Not dec
        txtOutputFolder.Enabled = Not dec
        txtInputFilePath.Enabled = Not dec
        txtKeyFilePath.Enabled = Not dec
        LV.Enabled = Not dec
        btnDecrypt.Enabled = Not dec
        btnAbort.Enabled = dec

        If Not decrypting Then
            Me.Text = "TS Decrypter and Joiner v1.0"
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```